# trying to create PDF Portfolios with horizontal tab layout

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to build PDF Portfolios with horizontal tab layout; it appears, that the only way to get this done would be to utilize a custom portfolio navigator built in Flash (PDF spec supports such portfolio navigators), this navigator needs to be built separately and then included in the PDF portfolio.

However, hopefully, by now there are several .NET libraries out there that can get this done without using Flash ?